# Ionic working in browser not in device

Tags: cordova, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am understanding Ionic. My custom css are working fine in browser.I'm expecting a blue color 'binesh' and an edit symbol
[image]

**but in device it is not working.** [image]

I was actually trying to work with ionicons which started to work fine in browser. but when i build on device its not working. I got doubt on css file not getting added and so i added my own css file. That also behaving same way(seems css is not working)

This is how i added css file to index.html and solution explorer shows build placed things in correct folder
[image]

And app.css is as follows
[image]

And I'm using this in Hello-ionic as folows
[image]

I'm wasting about 3 days in this area and don't know what i'm doing wrong. Please help....

Thanks & Regards
Binesh

Comment: did you build it for the respective platform?

Comment: Ya... I ran coomand 'ionic build android'. Then i ran 'ionic run android'

Comment: I got the reason. But Its not at all fare. The path css file holding is behaving as case sensitive. Have to report on ionic team. I'm having path as 'progmanSpecific' instead 'progManSpecific'

Answer (score -1):

This is a problem ionic team have to handle. The path for the css file is case sensitive made me loss of 3 days. I was having path 'progmanSpecific' instead 'progManSpecific'.  Now the question is how can i contact them?